# Send Http Request to .Net Server

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire

i want to send post request to .Net server. there is my code for post request:

```
  public func SendPostHttpRequest(baseURL: String, parameter: [String:Any], closure:@escaping ((_ success:JSON,_ error:NSError?) -> Void)) {
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {
      var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
      urlRequest.setValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      urlRequest.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: parameter)
      manager.request(urlRequest).responseString { response in
        debugPrint(" HTML error -------> \(response)")
      }
      manager.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON) :
          closure(JSON,nil)
        case .failure(let error):
          closure(nil,error as NSError)
          debugPrint("get error ---> \((error.localizedDescription)) ")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

that is define Extension for set URLEncodedFormData to request

```
 extension URLRequest {
        private static let alloweCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789  -_.*@$!#/:+[]\n")
          public mutating func setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: [String: Any]) {
            var encodedParameters = ""
            for (key, value) in parameters {

              if !encodedParameters.isEmpty {
                encodedParameters += "&"
              }
              encodedParameters += URLRequest.urlEncoded(value: key) ?? ""
              encodedParameters += "="

              let valuee = value
              if let boolValue = valuee as? Bool {
                encodedParameters += "\(boolValue)"
              }
              if let intValue = valuee as? Int {
                encodedParameters += "\(intValue)"
              }
              if let stringValue = valuee as? String {
                encodedParameters += (URLRequest.urlEncoded(value: stringValue) ?? "")
              }
            }
            self.httpMethod = "POST"
            self.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            self.httpBody = encodedParameters.data(using: .utf8)
          }

          private static func urlEncoded(value: String?) -> String? {

            return value?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: alloweCharacters)!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
          }
        }
```

i have an issue in send variables with different types to server. 
in server side i get this error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think because I'm sending all the parameters to the string, the server side does not figure out the bool and integer variables.

this is request object class, My question now is that the parameter type in integer whit setURLEncodedFormData method send as integer type to server or String?

```
class RegisterRequest: NSObject {
  var Usertoken: String!
  var ProffessionId: Int?
  override init() {
    self.Usertoken = ""
    self.ProvinceId = nil
}
}
```

Comment: What format your server accepts?

Comment: for example, I should for Integer format in server side send Integer parameter.

Comment: @TheTiger and content type that support is Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: For `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the body of the `HTTP` message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand (&), and names are separated from values by the equals symbol (=). An example of this would be: 

`MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo`

Comment: @TheTiger thanks for reply in setURLEncodedFormData method exactly i do that. i'm update my question. Please look at it